# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'credential')

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

i have this error :  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'credential')
when i try to

signInWithCredential

i have client side (react) that use GoogleLogin :
and i always get the error above :

```
V  exports.signInWithGoogle = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        console.log('Received data:', data);
        //return data  
        const auth = admin.auth();
        const credential = admin.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.credential);
        // Sign in with the Google credential
        const result = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
       
        // Handle the successful sign-in result
        return { success: true, user: result.user };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during Google Sign-In:', error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Google Sign-In failed');
    }
```

and i always get the error i mentioned above , this is the line where i get the problem :

```
const credential = admin.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.credential);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is that ```V``` supposed to be there?  What is ```admin```?

Comment: Shouldn't it be firebase.auth.GoogleauthProvider?  Also, possible hint in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330221/firebase-auth-googleauthprovider-credential-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

The Admin SDK doesn't have the concept of a currently signed-in user, so t here is no way to call `signInWithCredential` from the Firebase Admin SDK.

It's unclear why you're trying to do this (also see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but the common flow is that you sign in the user to Firebase in the client-side application code and (if needed) [get the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) and pass it to the server, where you can [verify that ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).